# Keeping data in model safe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

Suppose I were to have a web application and a view called `innerPage` for the application who's model looks something like this:

```
public class innerPageModel
{
    public bool isFirstTime = true;
    public List<int> threadIDList;


}
```

And here is the controller for my `innerPage`:

```
public ActionResult innerPage(InnerPageModel model)
{
   if (model.isFirstTime == true)
   {
       Thread t = new Thread(Work);
       model.threadIDList.Add(t.ManagedThreadID);
       model.isFirstTime = false);

   } 
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write((model.threadIDList.Count).toString());
}
```

Now my `innerPage` view is being refreshed every 5 seconds and therefore traversing my `innerPage` controller each time. The problem is that all of the data in my model is being reset after every time I traverse the controller (Everytime it goes inside the if-block, indicating that `model.isFirstTime` is being reset to true when I only want to traverse that if-block on the first time). Likewise, my `model.threadIDList` is being reset everytime through.

Is there a way for me to save the data in my model such that it isn't lost everytime my view refreshes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC model assumes the controller will be invoked, return an ActionResult and then be done.

It [does not seem safe](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) to kick off threads in the controller action.

If you need data to remain between HTTP requests, you can store it in the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) or in [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx), depending on whether the data is per-user or global to the website.

If you need true background processing, look at

- [WebBackgrounder](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder)
- [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)
- [FluentScheduler](http://fluentscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I went ahead an stored my data in a session. Phil Haack brings up an interesting point I hadn't thought of in that article. I'm a bit shaky on how to implement the `IRegisteredObject` in my application though. Since what I'm going to be waiting for are `Thread` objects, who will be execution the `Work()` method defined in my controller class, would I have `Thread` implement the `IRegisteredObject` interface? Or would I have the controller class implement it?